# convert parquet to json for dynamodb import

Tags: pyspark, amazon-dynamodb

I am using AWS Glue jobs to backup dynamodb tables in s3 in parquet format to be able to use it in Athena.

If I want to use these parquet format s3 files to be able to do restore of the table in dynamodb, this is what I am thinking - read each parquet file and convert it into json and then insert the json formatted data into dynamodb (using pyspark on the below lines)

```
# set sql context
parquetFile = sqlContext.read.parquet(input_file)
parquetFile.write.json(output_path)
```

Convert normal json to dynamo expected json using - https://github.com/Alonreznik/dynamodb-json

Does this approach sound right? Are there any other alternatives to this approach?

Comment: You can write directly to dynamodb from spark using [emr-dynamodb-connector](https://github.com/awslabs/emr-dynamodb-connector). This way, no need to convert to json.

Comment: Thanks, this helped, I was able to import into dynamo using hive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach will work, but you can write directly to DynamoDB. You just need to import a few `jar`s when you run `pyspark`. Have a look at this:
https://github.com/audienceproject/spark-dynamodb

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can use AWS Glue to directly convert Parquet format into JSON, then create a lambda function that triggers on S3 put and load into DyanmoDB

https://medium.com/searce/convert-csv-json-files-to-apache-parquet-using-aws-glue-a760d177b45f