# bulk load parquet data from s3 to dynamob table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb

UPDATE 02/06:
So, for now I was able to accomplish said task as below:

```
%python
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

import zlib
import json
import boto3
from datetime import datetime

from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark import sql
import os
#call to outside function to get AWS creds
s3_client = get_boto(spark)

small_df = spark.read.format('parquet').options(header=True,inferSchema=True).load('path-to-s3')

#convert all columns to String dtype
to_string_df = small_df.select([F.col(c).cast("string") for c in small_df.columns])
# upload to another s3 bucket as a compressed csv file
to_string_df.coalesce(1).write.mode("overwrite").option("compression","gzip").csv('<path-to-s3>')
```

Once I have the compressed csv file into the s3 location, I manually am able to kick off DynamoDB import from that s3 bucket, and was able to create a new DynamoDB table.
However, im now running into issues such as:

```
{
    "itemS3Pointer": {
        "bucket": "my-s3-bucket",
        "key": "csv-file-name.csv",
        "itemIndex": 9059
    },
    "importArn": "arn:aws:dynamodb:****",
    "errorMessages": [
        "Item size has exceeded the maximum allowed size"
    ]
}
```

Will keep on updating as i find more solutions! Thanks to the community for being patient with me.

Scenario:

Say a single s3 bucket contains 300+ objects and the total size of all these obects range from 1GB-2.5GBs
I will be having multiple such s3 buckets.But, for simplicity say i just have 1 s3 bucket to start with.

Before asking this question I did check the relevant links like [Loading parquet file from S3 to DynamoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55804623/loading-parquet-file-from-s3-to-dynamodb)

But, for my use case:

1. I want to bulk load from s3 to dynamodb.and I landed upon  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/S3DataImport.HowItWorks.html
2. Unfortunately, if I follow that approach,"parquet" format isn't supported today.

What have I done till date?

1. read parquet files from s3 then
2. create a local pandas dataframe out of it.
3. convert the rows in the dataframe into JSON strings
4. Use batch_writer to write the dataframe to DynamoDB

However the above approach is also costly in terms of money spent on DynamoDB writes.

Hence, the use case mentioned in the above link works perfectly for me i.e.

- be able to create a new table on every ingestion
- be able to bulk load data into this new table from s3

I am just stuck on the parquet conversion

Then I came up with a second approach:

1. Set up AWS Glue job to read that data from s3 in parquet format
2. apply transformation and dump into DynamoDB

But, I am not sure whether/if any WriteCapacity will be consumed with the second approach else all those efforts in saving costs on writes will be gone in vain.

Any pointers or am I just thinking in the wrong direction?

Answer (score 0):

I have a blog post coming out to solve this problem in the next 1-2 months, it's currently in draft stage.

Essentially what you need to do is create DDB-JSON from your parquet data. You can do that using the serialiser in boto3:

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.24.61/_modules/boto3/dynamodb/types.html

Create S3 files of items that suit the format expected by the import:

`{Item:{....}},`